# Can you explain the usage of "can have been" in the context?

Tags: modal-verbs, perfect-aspect

While reading *Facing Unpleasant Facts: Narrative Essays*
by George Orwell, I stumbled by the sentence

> When this episode happened I do not think I can have been less than twelve years old.

([Source](http://books.google.com/books?id=WREtVBBT9lEC&pg=PA261&lpg=PA261&dq="When+this+episode+happened+I+do+not+think+I+can+have+been+less+than+twelve+years+old."&source=bl&ots=mVW6yOFjnp&sig=K4iB3OFXJ8qkXp4yWg0smxqza4U&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwif3enEpuXSAhVS-GMKHRI4AvIQ6AEIIzAD#v=onepage&q=%22When%20this%20episode%20happened%20I%20do%20not%20think%20I%20can%20have%20been%20less%20than%20twelve%20years%20old.%22&f=false))

Can you explain the usage of *can have been* in the context?

Comment: I think we have to trust Eric Blair, here. He was a master of the language. It's an emphatic form of "I think it not possible that I was as young as twelve."

Comment: @deadrat yeah, he was great indeed, and thank you for your kind reply, you've made it much clearer to me!

Comment: The use of the modal "... I can have been less than .." (instead of the non-modal "...I was less than.. ") implies a greater degree of uncertainty by the author as to his age when the episode happened.

Answer (score -6):

*"When this episode happened I do not think I can have been less than twelve years old."*

First, it's COULD not CAN.

Second, it's an awkward sentence construction. It's better to say: *I think I could not have been...* than *I don't think I can have been...*

The meaning is what Kate Bunting said: "he cannot remember his exact age at the time, but thinks he must have been at least twelve."

To make the meaning easier to grasp, just remove unnecessary words. Example:
"*When that happened, I could not have been less than twelve*."

Comment: -1 The OP correctly quotes the source, which has *can*.

Comment: -1 It's not everyday I see Orwell's prose criticised as being awkward.